# which and sudo not using the same path

Tags: centos, sudo, path

```
$ which reboot

/usr/bin/reboot

$ sudo reboot

Sorry, user myusername is not allowed to execute '/sbin/reboot' as root
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it has something to do with this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why

So sudo changes the path, but passes it unchanged to the command. So it uses /sbin/reboot for the reboot command, but passes the usual path to the which command (which consequently finds sudo in /usr/bin/reboot).

Comment: I think you're right. The secure_path option in my sudoers file is the following: `Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`. Your link helped me figure out what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

when you run a command as root, files inside the sbin folder have a higher priority than the other folders in your path. Thats why sudo chooses /sbin/reboot. You have to use /sbin/reboot in your sudoers file, or you have to explicitly call sudo /usr/bin/reboot

Comment: thanks. However, even when running `which reboot` as root, the result is still /usr/bin/reboot.

Answer (score 0):

What this is telling you is that your `sudo` rights do not include the ability to use the `reboot` application.  The PATH is not being modified; it can find `reboot` just fine.

`cat /etc/sudoers`, and modify with `visudo` as necessary.

Comment: I had added /usr/bin/reboot with visudo. My user should be able to do a reboot with sudo according to my sudoers file. But instead, I'm asked my password and then I get the message decribed in the OP.

Comment: The only CentOS box I have is 5.9 (mostly Ubuntu here), but it looks like /usr/bin/reboot is a link to another application.

Comment: If you can use `visudo`, why don't you give yourself permissions to `/sbin/reboot`?

Comment: I allowed /sbin/reboot, as well as /sbin/shutdown in visudo. When I run `$ sudo /sbin/reboot` I get this message: `reboot: Unable to execute shutdown: Permission denied`

Comment: This last message seems to be caused by the NOEXEC option in my sudoers file. Apparently reboot is calling /bin/bash. I wonder why.